# Protractor JavaScript Gets Text Tag h1

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm struggling to get text from web element.  I would like to return the text to the function caller, but it always returns null.

```
<div _ngcontent-pet-c4 class="intro-content">
  <h1 _ngcontent-pet-c4>Hello World Welcome!</h1>
</div>
```

then i'm trying to get the text at tag h1

```
function loadWebsite(url)
{
  try{
    var retText = null;
    browser.get(url);
    browser.sleep(5000);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    var eleWelcomeTxt = element(by.css(".intro-content"));
    browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(eleWelcomeTxt), 5000);

    eleWelcomeTxt.getText().then(function(text){
      retText = text;
    });
  }catch(err){
    console.log("exception error: " + err.message);
  }

  return retText;
}
```

The function always returns null;

Comment: `Protractor` APIs are Async,  therefor your `return retText;` will be executed prior to `eleWelcomeTxt.getText()`, so `retText ` is always null.

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1. change the css selector
element(by.css(".intro-content h1"));

Issue 2.  promise to wrap your code

```
async function loadWebsite(url)
{
return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{

try{
       await browser.get(url);
       await browser.sleep(5000);
       browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
       let eleWelcomeTxt = element(by.css(".intro-content h1"));
       await browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(eleWelcomeTxt), 5000);
       let text = await eleWelcomeTxt.getText();
       return resolve(text);
       }catch(err){
        console.log("exception error: " + err.message);
        return reject();
      } 
})
}
```

Comment: webdriver.WebElement.getText will get the visible innerText of this element, including sub-elements.

Comment: @Bharath Kumar S, thanks, and is it possible to simpler code?

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElement), the `EC.textToBePresentInElement` method accepts 2 arguments

```
EC.textToBePresentInElement(element, elementText)
```

Actually not very sure about what you are trying to do, just give you an example of how to validate the text in an element:

```
/*
 * get element Text
 * @param container - the container of the desired element
 * @param elementToGet - the class name of the element to get
 * @param value - value to check
 */
expectElementTextToEqual: function (container, elementName, expectedVal) {
    ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    this.elementloadedInDOM(container);
    let cont = element.all(by.className(container)).first();
    cont.isDisplayed();
    let el = cont.all(by.className(elementName)).first();
    el.isEnabled();
    el.isDisplayed();
    expect(el.getText()).toEqual(expectedVal);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Basically I"m try to return plain text from a promise.  If I use "expect()" that is no problem but I'm not testing for valid text here.  I just want to return the text back to the caller.